# Which is best practice for Exception Handling: Catching exception at inner level v/s Catching exception once at top level

Tags: java, exception

Catching exception at inner level:

```
if (type.equals("A")) {
    try {
        //some code
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Parsing Exception. Caused By: ", e);
    }
} else if (type.equals("B")) {
    try {
        //some code
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Parsing Exception. Caused By: ", e);
    }
} else if (type.equals("C")) {
    try {
        //some code
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Parsing Exception. Caused By: ", e);
    }
}
```

or catching exception once:

```
try {
        if (type.equals("A")) {
            //some code
        } else if (type.equals("B")) {
            //some code
        } else if (type.equals("C")) {
            //some code
        }
    } |
    catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Parsing Exception. Caused By: ", e);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Neither. Catch it at the level which is best equipped to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the second approach fits the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and is recommended. But, ideally you should only catch exceptions if you can recover from them.

If the only thing you want is to log them, it's preferred to have this code as high up the call chain as possible. Going through the logs and seeing the same exception logged multiple times is no fun and just makes debugging and maintenance harder.

Answer (score 0):

There is only possibility of executing a condition. Since you are catching only one specific exception having only one try-catch is fine here. Keep the second snippet.

Comment: maybe your answer fits the concrete examples, but a general answer to the described problem is not suitable.

Comment: @Joshua Do you mean reverse ? I said about the current problem. Not a general scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch a single exception and you want to execute the same set of statements in the `catch` block, then it is okay to catch it once.
But if you want to catch several different exceptions or handle the same exception differently for different statements, then you should create multiple `catch` blocks.